# Java boiler plate code: connection management

Tags: java, connection-pooling, meta

We typically have the following code when dealing with connection pooling:

```
connection c = pool.borrow();
try {
    business-logic-using-connection(c);
}
catch(connectionException e) {
    connectionBad = true;
} 
finally{
    if (connectionBad) {
        pool.evict(c);
    } else {
       pool.return(c);
    }
 }
```

The question is how to make this boiler plate code simpler such that one can do something like:

```
getConnectionAndDoWork(pool, business-logic-code)
```

where one can plugin their business logic, and don't have to repeat the same connection manage code all over the place. One way is to create an interface for business-logic-code such as `doWorkWithConnection` that takes a connection and do some work. However, that restricts what business logic code should return;

is there a better way to do it in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Use the callback pattern like Spring uses for [programmatic transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic).

```
interface PooledConnectionCallback<T> {
  T doWithConnection(Connection c);
}

Pool pool = new Pool(poolParams);
Integer returnedValue = pool.execute(
  new PooledConnectionCallback<Integer>() {
    public Integer doWithConnection(Connection c) {
      int someReturnValue = businessLogicUsingConnection(c);
      return someReturnValue;
    }});
```

In the `Pool#execute` method you can have the boilerplate code you require to handle exceptions and cleanup.

Comment: what's pool#execute signature?

Comment: `<T> T Pool#execute(PooledConnectionCallback<T>)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring, consider using the JdbcTemplate or NamedParameterJdbcTemplate:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html

Even if you are not using Spring, you can still use the same basic template method pattern. Just Google "template method". There are lots of articles about it.